# Restart a UserControl in Windows Forms-App (.Net Framework) C#

Tags: c#, .net, forms, window

I have a Windows Forms App in C# with multiple UserControls.

In the UserControl1 I create panels dynamically, each panel containing multiple elements (checkbox, label listbox, picturebox, and multiple comboboxes). The values inside these elements differs between panels because I import the values from a Database. Also, I can add or remove elements from the listbox. Basically each panel is a presentation for a Pizza menu where you select the size (each size has its own price) and add or remove ingredients (from the listbox).

If you select one (or more) of the pizza's it is added in the UserControl2 (designated as a shopping cart). You can select multiple (different) pizza items from the UserControl1, and all of them will appear in the UserControl2 in the "shopping cart".

All these UserControls are contained in a panel in a Form and can be accessed by clicking a corresponding button.

My question is, how do I reload the UserControl1 from UserControl2?

Basically, after I'm done making an "order" (which can have multiple different items), I want to make a new "order" and I want the UserControl1 to look just like it was when I started the app.

I realize that I have to call the UserControl1_Load() method, but how do I do that from the UserControl2?

Or is there another method of "resetting" the UserControl1?

Obviously, I'm kind of new to C# so, please, have mercy on my soul.

Thank you very much in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I would implement an interface which each UserControl should implement to support this feature. The interface is a contract describing that the control has implemented a method. Just try to cast all usercontrols to that interface to support the restart functionality.

You should change it for your needs, but here is an example:

```
public interface ISupportInitialize
{
    void Initialize();
}
```

---

```
public partial class MyUserControl : UserControl, ISupportInitialize
{
    public MyUserControl()
    {
        // whatever you need to initialize
        Initialize();
    }

    public void Initialize()
    {
        // remove old content if exists
        // add new content
    }
}
```

---

And in your main window:

```
public void ReInitializeControls()
{
    // assume that panel1 contains the controls.
    var userControlsWithInitialize = panel1.Controls.OfType<ISupportInitialize>();

    foreach(var control in userControlsWithInitialize)
        control.Initialize();
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The Panels are created "dynamically". 
Basically I the UserControl1_Load(), I import the data from the database, then I put it in a DataView. After I use a foreach loop to go through the DataView, and generate for each element a panel. I use a method to generate the panel that is called in the before mentioned foreach loop.

Answer (score 0):

Calling the Load() method may not be sufficient. If you want a total reset behavior, you can remove the current control and add a brand new one in place of it.

Assuming you know how to implement an event handler, this goes inside the user control which triggers the reset operation, as a member variable:

```
public EventHandler OnOrderCompleted;
```

And when the order is completed, the control should invoke:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (OnOrderCompleted != null)
    {
        OnOrderCompleted.Invoke(this, new EventArgs());
    }
}
```

To keep coupling at minimum, this control should not directly know about the user control to be reset, but should inform any observers about the completion of an order. In our case, this can be the form hosting all the controls: (We name the triggering control `orderControl` here)

```
public Form2()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    orderControl.OnOrderCompleted += OnOrderCompleted;
}

private void OnOrderCompleted(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Point currentLocation = productsControl.Location;
    Controls.Remove(productsControl);
    productsControl = new UserControl1();
    productsControl.Location = currentLocation;
    Controls.Add(productsControl);
}
```

Hope this helps.